# Tomcat 8 Netscaler SSL (on both)

Tags: tomcat, ssl, keystore, netscaler

We are using Netscaler for Load balancing and Failover to 2 tomcat servers.

SSL is configured on Netscaler with cert CN (somename.fqdn)

SSL is configured on Tomcat with cert CN (webserver1.fqdn) and (webserver2.fqdn)

netscaler URL: https://somename

web server1 URL: https://webserver1

web server 2 URL: https://webserver2

1. When we try the https://somename  with SSL turned on both netscaler and the servers we receive a page can not be displayed turn on TLS error(it is turned on), different browsers etc.
2. When we try the https://webserver1 https://webserver2 we are able to get to the application.
3. When we turn OFF the SSL on webservers and then try the https://somename (pointing to port 80)it works.

I was asked to import the Cert created for Netscaler into my tomcat keystore, but once I do that, I get the same TLS error.

I was then asked to use CN of (somename.fqdn) to generate my csr, and import that cert, and it is still the same error (TLS).  The only way I can get the SSL to work  is use the servername.fqdn to generate the webserver certs and use their URLS, but not the netscaler cert, and URL.

Comment: Try putting all three names into your cert.

Comment: Coeur, your response resolved the issue by using SAN when generating keystore.

Comment: @sapaa I am into a similar issue. I am using a wildcard certificate provided by an external CA. I know it is pretty old post but do you remember the process of using SAN?